# changing slider image depending on the clicked button

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, slider

I am using slick slider, to show some images, but also, it needs to display a diferent image depending on the button clicked.

My thoughts were to do it through data-attr; so, I have added a data-attr to the anchor (which works as button), and the same data-attr to the slide that belongs to that button. On click, I want to change the displaying slide, to the one which belongs to the button.

Nothing I have done so far seems to work... I need to use slick slider, as it is the one the client is using at the moment, and it can not be changed.

html

```
<div class="sidebar col-xs-4">
  <a class="switch" href="#" data-attr="lion">
    <span class="text">The lion</span>
  </a>
  <a class="switch" href="#" data-attr="bear">
    <span class="text">The bear</span>
  </a>
  <a class="switch" href="#" data-attr="dog">
    <span class="text">The dog</span>
  </a>
   <a class="switch" href="#" data-attr="pigeon">
   <span class="text">The pigeon</span></a>
</div>
   <div class="mainBanner col-xs-8">
      <div class="slide" data-attr="lion">
        <img src="https://s29.postimg.org/uh5ln0yaf/lion.jpg" alt=""/>
        <p class="text transpDark">The lion is the king of the animals</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide" data-attr="bear">
        <img src="https://s27.postimg.org/qvo00fpvn/bear.jpg" alt=""/>
        <p class="text transpDark">Bears sleep during the winter</p>
      </div>
        <div class="slide" data-attr="dog">
        <img src="https://s27.postimg.org/xw0gvt2hf/dog.jpg" alt=""/>
        <p class="text transpDark">Dog is the most loyal friend you will ever have</p>
      </div>
       <div class="slide" data-attr="pigeon">
        <img src="https://s30.postimg.org/nd79rqnvl/pigeon.jpg" alt=""/>
        <p class="text transpDark">Pigeons are flying rats</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
.switch {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: block;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
}
.text.transpDark {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: khaki;
  color: black;
  bottom:0;
  left: 5px;
}
```

js

```
$(".mainBanner").slick({
    arrows: false    
});
$( '.sidebar').on( 'click', '.switch', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var button = $(this).attr("data-attr");
      var slide = $(".mainBanner .slide");
      var dataArray = [];
        $(slide).each(function() {
         dataArray.push($(this).attr("data-attr"));
      });
     if($.inArray(button, dataArray) > -1){
       $(".mainBanner .slide").removeClass("slick-cloned slick-current slick-active").attr({
           "data-slick-index": "-1",
           "aria-hidden": "true"
       });
       $(".mainBanner .slide[data-attr="+ button +"]").addClass("slick-current slick-active").attr({
           "data-slick-index": "1",
           "aria-hidden": "false"
       });
}  
});
```

And here the jsfiddle, for a clearer idea

https://jsfiddle.net/cyrz161r/1/

Any suggestions?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `slickGoTo` method. Get the index of your slide with `dataArray.indexOf()`

I updated your js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cyrz161r/8/

Comment: WOw, thank you so much. It is impressive I can be working with this for hours and not getting it working and some people can deal with it within minutes :( It frustrates me so much!
It is great, thank you Dennis

Comment: Just noticed that theres a little error in the fiddle. You have to decrement the slideIndex by 1. Otherwise it jumps to the wrong slide: